# How do I fix the url when clicking on portfolio item?

Tags: customization, urls

Right now I'm working on the portfolio section of this [website](http://ligature23.ufdesigners.com/work/), and I noticed that whenever I click on a work, it adds a # followed by the whole URL of what I want. For example, it goes from

```
http://ligature23.ufdesigners.com/work/
```

to

```
http://ligature23.ufdesigners.com/work/#http://ligature23.ufdesigners.com/work/soft-money/
```

The only plug-ins I have activated are the ones that came with the theme, and I have my permalinks set to Post Name. Any guesses as to what it could be that's causing this?

Comment: You will need to post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Save that to a file (something.js) and upload it to your server. Then add the following to your functions.php (remember to set up a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) if you aren't using one):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_load_scripts' );
function prefix_load_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'something', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path/to/file/something.js', array('jquery'), true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'something' );
}
```